# Convert from string to int in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, bids, foxpro

I'm converting a database from one structure into a new structure.  The old database is FoxPro and the new one is SQL server.  The problem is that some of the data is saved as char data in foxpro but are actually foreign key tables.  This means they need to be int types in sql.  Problem is When i try to do a data conversion in SSIS from any of the character related types to an integer, I get something along the following error message:

There was an error with the output column "columnName"(24) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (22).  The column status returned was : "The value could not be converted because of potential loss of data".

How do i convert from a string or character to an int without getting the potential loss of data error.  I hand checked the values and it looks like all of them are small enough to fit into an int data type.

Comment: Can you please provide an example value that is to be converted?  And also provide the exact data type of the source (as interpreted by SSIS)

Comment: If you can get hold of a copy Of Visual FoxPro 9.0 (MSDN sub maybe) you could use the SQL Server Upsizing Wizard in that.

Comment: @devlincarnate the values all look like integers but they are saved as a character type.  example: 34563927342

Comment: @AlanB could you expand on this.  I do have foxpro 9.  what is the sql server up-sizing wizard?

Comment: You do realize that 34563927342 exceeds the max value for integer, right?  You would need to use int64 / bigint.

Comment: It's pretty much what it says on the tin: it takes a Visual FoxPro database container and associated tables and creates and pouplates an SQL Server with the structure and data. Here's an updated version: https://github.com/StevenBlack/VFPx-SQL-Server-Upsizing-Wizard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data source -> Data Conversion Task.

In Data Conversion Task, click Configure Error Output

For Error and Truncation, change it from Fail Component to Redirect Row.

Now you have two paths. Good data will flow out of the DCT with the proper types. The bad data will go down the Red path. Do something with it. Dump to a file, add a data view and inspect, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Values like 34563927342 exceed the [max size for integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx).  You should use Int64 / bigint